# jQuery Variable Not Accessible Outside of Function

Tags: jquery, global-variables

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $.wordlist = []; 
   $.get('../wordlist.txt', function(data){
     $.wordlist = data.split('\n');
   });
   console.log($.wordlist);
 });
```

The `console.log($.wordlist)` consistently returns an empty array.  The same `console.log` call in the `$.get()` function successfully returns the complete array.

What am I doing wrong and how do I make this array globally accessible?

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous.

Comment: The get is async request, so your console.log shows variable before get will be performed. Use success callback as mentioned here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.get` method is asynchronous. This means it is still executing when `console.log` is run. You need to place *all* code which relies on the data returned by the request within the callback function:

```
var wordlist = []; 
$.get('../wordlist.txt', function(data){
    wordlist = data.split('\n');
    console.log(wordlist);
});
```

Also note that it's not a good idea to add your own variables to the jQuery (`$`) namespace.

Comment: Why do you answer it even though it is duplicate?

Comment: 1) Because it's not an exact duplicate - the OP is not returning from a function. 2) Because not polluting the `$` with extraneous properties/functions is an important point to be made.

Comment: OKay, thanks. That clarifies. `:)`

Comment: Asynchronicity completely explains why this variable later returns complete data to other functions.  Thanks for the jQuery namespace tips.

Comment: @RyanFoley no problem - glad to help.